# Show text fields larger than 65000 characters

Tags: crystal-reports

My text field can contain up to 200,000 characters. But my report only shows the first 65,000. How can I display the entire field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never need more than 200,000 characters (as mentioned above) you can get by with breaking the field in question into a minimum of 4 parts. (`65000 x 4 = 260000`)

1. Write a custom SQL statement in Crystal by going to the Database Expert and choosing Add Command
2. Instead of pulling back the single TextField from your table, pull back 4 individual fields.
3. Configure these individual fields to, when necessary, share the load. The first field gets characters 0 to 64999, the second field gets characters 65000 to 130000, etc.
4. Write logic inside the SQL to leave these fields blank when they're not needed. I.e. if you only have 1000 characters, field 1 gets all of it but fields 2 through 4 can be blank.

Then inside your report, concatenate the new fields into a single formula:

```
{Command.Field1} & {Command.Field2} & {Command.Field3} & {Command.Field4}
```